# Android password visibility toggle not working with support library 25?

Tags: android, passwords, android-support-library, textinputlayout

I have implemented a TextInputLayout with a password field in the usual way:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/returning_password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/prompt_password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

This worked fine when using the Android support library up to version 24.0.2, but after switching to 25.0.1:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:25.0.1'
```

I no longer see the password visibility toggle (a.k.a. "eye icon") in the widget. Changing to the latest version 25.1.0 does not fix this problem.

Is there anything that I missed and need to change in combination with the support library 25, or could this be an Android issue?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Try it this way.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/returning_password"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/prompt_password"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:textSize="14sp" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

This might be helpful for you!!

> The TextInputLayout password toggle is now disabled by default to avoid unnecessarily overwriting developer-specified end drawables. It may be manually enabled via the passwordToggleEnabled XML attribute.

[Recent Support Library Revisions](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html)

Comment: Perfect answer, thanks! That fixed it straight away, and I'll keep an eye on that link the next time the library version is updated.

Comment: for remove password roboto default typeface use `android:typeface="normal"`

Comment: How to achieve the same functionality with support library 23.4.0

Comment: Sometimes the icon maybe white, so add **app:passwordToggleTint="some color"**  for visibility.

Comment: In Kotlin it is deprecated, should use app:endIconMode="password_toggle"

Answer (score 6):

if you use Jetpack then

add  these dependencies

```java
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
```

and  add  **`app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"`** in xml 
  and one more thing, use **`inputType= textPassword`** and if you use rather than this then toggle button won't be shown.

Instead of using

```xml
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/returning_password"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/prompt_password"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:textSize="14sp" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

, you need to use

```xml
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/returning_password"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/prompt_password"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:textSize="14sp" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: Really helpful answer for those who migrated app to androidx.. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to add following:

```
app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
```

just change your dependency to:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'
```

That's the same bug I faced too while updating dependency.

Edit:

Now

`app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"`

is working with,

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">
```

**app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">**

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edt_password"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Password"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:textSize="16sp" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.1'

compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.1'

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'

compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:25.0.1'